# Adjusting grid template columns for specific TextField within a grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a ReactJS project and using a Box component from Material UI with a grid layout to display a form. The form contains multiple fields, and I want to customize the grid template columns for a specific TextField component named 'description.' The parent Box component has a general setting for gridTemplateColumns, but I need the 'description' TextField to have a different grid configuration. I want the `description` textfield to have `gridTemplateColumns="repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr))"`. the rest of the fields still follow the main grid layout set by the parent Box component.

This is relevent code:

````
                    display="grid"
                    gap="30px"
                    gridTemplateColumns="repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))"
                    sx={{
                        "& > div": { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 2" },
                    }}>

                    {fields.map((field) => (
                        <div key={field.name}>
                            {field.name === 'description' ? (
                                <TextField
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    rows={10}
                                    fullWidth
                                    multiline
                                    label={field.label}
                                    name={field.name}
                                    value={formik.values[field.name]}
                                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                    color="success"
                                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                    error={formik.touched[field.name] && Boolean(formik.errors[field.name])}
                                    helperText={formik.touched[field.name] && formik.errors[field.name]}
                                    sx={{ gridColumn: "span 1" }}
                                />
                            ) : field.name === 'assignedTo' ? (
                                <Autocomplete
                                    fullWidth
                                    options={namesOfPeople.map((movie) => movie.label)}
                                    value={formik.values[field.name]}
                                    onChange={(newValue) => {
                                        formik.handleChange({
                                            target: { name: 'assignedTo', value: newValue },
                                        });
                                    }}
                                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                    getOptionLabel={(option) => {
                                        console.log('This is the value I have: ', option)
                                        return option
                                    }}
                                    renderInput={(params) => (
                                        <TextField
                                            {...params}
                                            color="success"
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            label="Assigned To"
                                            name="contact"
                                            error={formik.touched[field.name] && Boolean(formik.errors[field.name])}
                                            helperText={formik.touched[field.name] && formik.errors[field.name]}
                                            sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                        />
                                    )
                                    }
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <TextField
                                    fullWidth
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    label={field.label}
                                    type={field.type}
                                    name={field.name}
                                    value={formik.values[field.name]}
                                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                    color="success"
                                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                    error={formik.touched[field.name] && Boolean(formik.errors[field.name])}
                                    helperText={formik.touched[field.name] && formik.errors[field.name]}
                                    sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                                />
                            )}
                        </div>
                    ))}

                </Box>```

I've tried adjusting the sx prop for the 'description' field, but it doesn't seem to override the parent grid settings.

How can I update the code to ensure that the 'description' TextField has a specific grid layout, while the other components still follow the main grid layout set by the parent Box component?


I've tried adjusting the sx prop for the 'description' field, like this: 

// for the 'description' TextField
`sx={{ gridColumn: "span 1" }}` and I also tried this `gridTemplateColumns="repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr))"`

this doesn't seem to change the layout as expected.
````